# template type name error when same name is used for static member function

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I have the following code:

```
struct test
{
    static void T()
    {
    }
    
    template<typename T>
    void f(T* t)
    {
    }
    
    template<typename T>
    T* get()
    {
        return new T();     
    }
};

int main()
{
    test t;
    t.f(t.get<int>());
    
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles fine as it is, but if I move the definition outside the class it doesn't:

```
struct test
{
    static void T();
    
    template<typename T>
    void f(T* t);
    
    template<typename T>
    T* get();
};

void test::T()
{
}

template<typename T>
void test::f(T* t)
{
}

template<typename T>
T* test::get()
{
    return new T();     
}

int main()
{
    test t;
    t.f(t.get<int>());
    
    return 0;
}
```

gcc error message:

```
#1 with x86-64 gcc 9.3
<source>:17:14: error: variable or field 'f' declared void
   17 | void test::f(T* t)
      |              ^
<source>:17:15: error: expected primary-expression before '*' token
   17 | void test::f(T* t)
      |               ^
<source>:17:17: error: 't' was not declared in this scope
   17 | void test::f(T* t)
      |                 ^
Compiler returned: 1
```

clang error message:

```
#1 with x86-64 clang 8.0.0
<source>:17:12: error: variable has incomplete type 'void'
void test::f(T* t)
           ^
<source>:17:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 't'
void test::f(T* t)
                ^
<source>:17:19: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
void test::f(T* t)
                  ^
                  ;
<source>:18:1: error: expected unqualified-id
{
^
<source>:24:16: error: unknown type name 'T'
    return new T();
               ^
5 errors generated.

Compiler returned: 1
```

MSVC 2019 error message:

```
#1 with x64 msvc v19.24
example.cpp

<source>(17): error C2065: 't': undeclared identifier
<source>(17): error C2182: 'f': illegal use of type 'void'
<source>(17): error C2350: 'test::f' is not a static member
<source>(17): note: see declaration of 'test::f'
<source>(17): error C2513: 'test::f': no variable declared before '='
<source>(18): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
Compiler returned: 2
```

It also compiles fine if it change `typename T` to `typename SomeOtherName` in `test::f` or if I rename `static void T()` to something else.

Can you please explain me why the first version compiles and the second doesn't? Can you point me to the standard wording for this error?

EDIT:
I've posted error message from different compilers. As @cigien pointed clang trunk compiles the second version

Comment: [clang](https://www.godbolt.org/z/UX5Gh4) is fine with it. I'm guessing it's a bug. (Don't know who's correct, though).

Comment: You get the same error for non-static member functions as well.

Comment: In `get` you have to explicitly give the type, there's no way for the compiler to imply it.

Comment: The one in the link in the first comment. It's clang trunk. Hmm, it doesn't work with clang 10.0 so maybe allowing it is a bug in clang trunk.

Comment: What I *think* is happening here is that, since the `test::` comes after the `template<typename T>` in the out-of-line definition of the function, the scope of `test` declaring the value `T` comes before the scope declaring the type template parameter `T` when searching for the meaning of the nam `T`, so `T* t` is taken to mean `T * t`: a multiplication of a value by `t`. Name lookup then fails for `t`, and you also get an error because treating `T * t` as an expression makes `void test::f(T * t)` look like a variable of `void` type and then the function body also has no function to attach to.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Seems to answer the question. So clang trunk bug in accepting it, then?

Comment: @cigien hm, clang trunk still finds a base name from that question. I'm now not so sure if this is a dup

Comment: @cigien Looks clang trunk bug to me

Comment: @cigien they are [tryna](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/search?q=DR458&type=Commits) implement http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_dr_status.html#458 in Clang 11, but doing it wrong

Comment: @cigien But see https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41309#c4 https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41309#c5

Answer (score 1):

Name lookup is very subtle for template parameters: the **priority** that they have among scopes depends not just on where the *template-head* appears but also on the entity for which it provides the template parameters.  [temp.local]/7 says

> In the definition of a member of a class template that appears outside of the class template definition, the name of a member of the class template hides the name of a *template-parameter* of any enclosing class templates (but not a *template-parameter* of the member if the member is a class or function template).

This doesn't literally apply here (`test` is not a class template), but it suggests that your out-of-line definition *should* be fine.  It's not entirely trivial for the compiler to know that since it needs to **identify** the member in order to decide whether it's a member template.  However, it *is* possible by carefully considering what part of the *declarator-id* uses template parameters from each *template-head*, so the rule shouldn't automatically be considered defective; Clang (trunk!) seems to be applying it correctly in this expanded sense, although (as pointed out in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62597745/template-type-name-error-when-same-name-is-used-for-static-member-function/62599547?noredirect=1#comment110703280_62599547) there is also an old CWG issue suggesting the opposite interpretation for this case.

Comment: This rule only applies to class template no?

Comment: `test` is not a template, so [temp.local]/7 doesn't apply. See also http://wg21.link/cwg458, where CWG think that such code should be ill-formed (Notes from the March 2004 meeting). There currently is an incorrect attempt to implement DR458 in Clang trunk.

Comment: GCC has not indeed implemented this rule : https://godbolt.org/z/Hkhk2c

Comment: You're both right that the rule doesn't apply as written, but I'm not sure about the CWG458 logic: it makes no sense that the template parameters of a member template would have higher priority than the members of an enclosing class _template_ but not of an enclosing class.  (The rule also fails to mention the template parameters of the class template itself, which could have been changed in the out-of-line definition to match a class member.)  I'll edit to hedge a bit more because this is such a mess.

Comment: Given how CWG458 is explicit about that non-template case should be ill-formed, this doens't look like an overlook. Are there any reflector discussions or something overriding CWG458 decision?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: The review of [P1787](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r4.html) will resolve the matter; I don’t think anyone noticed the disconnect from the current wording in the first pass, so I’ll be sure to bring it up next time.

Comment: So, P1787 [temp.local]/7 implements what was suggested by Erwin Unruh in http://wg21.link/cwg459, namely, puts template parameters scope in front of every other scope during lookup?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: It puts them immediately after the scopes associated with the template in question (including (non-dependent) base classes of a class template).

Comment: It's funny how the "proposed resolution" in cwg458 doesn't really address the very first example provided in cwg458...

Comment: _It puts them immediately after the scopes associated with the template in question_ I don't see how template parameter and not class member will be found according to P1787. Could you explain?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: The class scope contains the member template, so it is searched after the template parameter scope associated with that member template.

Comment: @rustyx: At the time, CWG decided that no wording change was needed for that example (but I think it’s unclear at best).